# Remove duplicate lines from threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a program that reads lines randomly from a file, and uses threading. The problem is that whenever it reads the lines from a file, it sometimes reads a duplicate line from the file. For instance, let's say I use 5 threads and my file looks like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

The program uses threading to read the lines randomly, but sometimes it can read line4, line3, line5, line2, line5 (again). So my question is how would I get rid of the line5 being a duplicate?

Code:

```
def get_token():
    tokens = []
    with open('pokens.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            tokens.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
    return tokens

def get_proxy():
    proxies = []
    with open('proxies.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            proxies.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
    return proxies

class Gen:
    def __init__(self, token, proxy=None):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

        proxy_ip_port = proxy

        proxy2 = Proxy()
        proxy2.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
        proxy2.http_proxy = proxy_ip_port
        proxy2.ssl_proxy = proxy_ip_port

        capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        proxy2.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")

        self.token = token
        self.proxy = proxy
        self.password = 'passwordhere'

    def register(self):
        print('hi')
        # Code continues with no duplicates


def worker(proxy=None):
    token_list = get_token()
    token = random.choice(token_list)

    d = Gen(token, proxy=proxy)
    d.register()

def main():
    threads = []

    num_thread = input('Number of Threads: ')
    num_thread = int(num_thread)

    proxies = get_proxy()

    for i in range(num_thread):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args= (random.choice(proxies), ))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: An easy fix (for either single-threaded or multithreaded implementations) would be to generate a list of integers from 1 to N in advance, then randomize the order of list, then give each worker a different section of the list and tell the worker to print out the lines at the line numbers specified in the sub-list you gave it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I did not understand that answer, could you give me a code example or something? I'm really lost here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simplified "toy version" of your program that I updated to do the following:

1. Read the tokens-file from the main thread, into a list
2. Randomly shuffle the order of the list
3. Give each worker a roughly-equally-sized subset of the tokens-list for it to choose from
4. Each worker merely prints out the data that it was given by the main thread (actually doing anything with the data is omitted, for clarity)

This approach avoid duplicates because any given token appears in the list only once, and each thread has been given a different subset of the list to choose tokens from.

```
import threading
import random

def read_tokens_list():
    tokens = []
    with open('pokens.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            tokens.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
    return tokens

def read_proxies_list():
    proxies = []
    with open('proxies.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            proxies.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
    return proxies

def worker(proxy,token_list):
    token = random.choice(token_list)
    print("Worker:  my proxy is [%s], my token list is %s, I've chosen [%s] as my token" % (proxy, token_list, token))

def main():
    threads = []

    num_thread = input('Number of Threads: ')
    num_thread = int(num_thread)

    proxies = read_proxies_list()

    token_list = read_tokens_list()                     # read in the pokens.txt file
    random.shuffle(token_list)                          # shuffle the list into random order
    tokens_per_worker = len(token_list) // num_thread   # how many tokens from the list each worker will get (roughly)

    for i in range(num_thread):
        if ((i+1)<num_thread):
           num_tokens_for_this_worker = tokens_per_worker   # give each worker an even share of the list
        else:
           num_tokens_for_this_worker = len(token_list)     # except the last worker gets whatever is left

        # we'll give the first (num_tokens_for_this_worker) tokens in the list to this worker
        tokens_for_this_worker = token_list[0:num_tokens_for_this_worker]

        # and remove those tokens from the list so that they won't get used by anyone else
        token_list = token_list[num_tokens_for_this_worker:]

        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(random.choice(proxies), tokens_for_this_worker, ))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but I have another question. If I wanted to remove the chosen token from the original pokens.txt file how would I do that? At first I though I could just rewrite the file without the token but I think that will break with threading right?

Comment: @Jarvn you would need to rewrite the file (updating the file in-place is technically possible but generally not worth the additional complexity, since you'll end up having to rewrite the majority of the file anyway).  You're correct that trying to write to the file from multiple threads would be problematic; you can avoid that simply by doing that operation from the main thread only.

Comment: Currently the code runs only once, but if I wanted to run the code inside a loop and print all the lines inside tokens.txt how would I do that?

Comment: Insert a for-loop or a while-loop, move the code you want to run multiple times into it, and add a print() statement into `read_proxies_list()`

Comment: I tried to, but then It doesn't use the threads and just runs the code once inside a loop